# Can't use  root_path in my Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using crummy, the breadcrumbs gem, and I need to set up the breadcrumbs in each controller.

When I use root_path in the Application Controller, to set up the top level of the breadcrumbs like this:

```
add_crumb "Home", root_path
```

I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `root_path' for ApplicationController:Class
```

I know root_path is defined, and I have tried this exact line in a different controller and it works there.

I cant use `add_crumb "Home", '/'` since I need every link to maintain some parameters for i18n

Any idea about what may be happening? Is this normal behaviour? Help!

Comment: actually it should not have happen.. can you gist exception trace..looks like issue could be some other..

Comment: on ruby console `app.root_path` `app.root_url` should work .. is it ??

Comment: Try running `rake routes` in your project directory - that will show all of your app's routes.  There should be a **root** route there, if not then that would explain your error. If you don't have a `root` route you can add one in **config/routes.rb**.
Mine looks like: `root :to => "home#index"`

Comment: @Sandip to your second comment, yes, it works. To the first: how can i do that?

Comment: do you have 
  root :to => "default_controller#default_action" in your routes.rb file ?

Comment: @Fivell Yes, I have that

Comment: than it might work! try to restart webrick

Comment: @agente_secreto You can gist `https://gist.github.com/` complete exception trace and paste url here. But it looks like the issue is with `add_crumb`.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same phenomenon, too.
Was supported as follows.

```
  before_filter :hoge

  def hoge
    add_crumb t("labels.links.home"), root_url
  end
```

Thanks.